# Trying to connect two databases to a php file and store user session

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

Ok, so what I'm trying to basically is connect two databases to my index.php file and then use one of the databases to log the user in and one of the other databases to store the session for the user.

What I cant figure out how to do is store the session of a user. What I want to do is have the users information to be shown such as email and username things like that and then when they logout I want that information to disappear with the session, but currently when a user logs-in the information stays the say from the old user and it doesnt change.

I've included my code below. In my code when I mention session like its a database thats because it is I created a database and table called session and my other database is called database and the table is called admin.

Index

```
<?php
 session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "****";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
// username and password sent from form

$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
$mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']);

$sql = "SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username = '$myusername' and passcode = '$mypassword'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$active = $row['active'];

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count == 1) { 
$session_id = session_id(); 
$sql = "INSERT INTO session(session_id,username) VALUES('$session_id','$myusername')";
mysqli_query($db,$sql); 
header("Location: test2.php");
}else {
         $error = "";
      }
   }
?>
```

Config

```
<?php
   define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
   define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', '******');
   define('DB_DATABASE', 'database');
   $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
?>
```

Session

```
<?php
 include('config.php');
 session_start();

 $user_check = $_SESSION['myusername'];

 $ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"select username from admin where username = '$user_check' ");

 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

 $login_session = $row['username'];

 ?>
```

Test 2 Page (This is the page I want to login to so it displays user info.)

```
<?php
 session_start();
 include("config.php");

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "database";
$dbname2 = "session";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $dbname2);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$session_id = session_id(); 

$sql = "SELECT id, username, passcode, email, Address, City, Country, Zip, FirstName, LastName, About FROM admin WHERE username = (SELECT username FROM session WHERE session_id = '$session_id')";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

?>
```

Comment: For one thing, you didn't select the `active` row for your `$sql = "SELECT id FROM admin` query. `mysqli_error($db)` on the query would have told you about it. **Edit:** Doesn't seem to matter, you're not using that `$active` variable anyway. So scratch this comment.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: Why do you need two separate databases?

Comment: I believe what your problem is, is that you are not destroying the session.

Comment: @tadman `mysqli_real_escape_string` is hardly manual escaping

Comment: A silly mistake I made I don't actually need to make two different databases. I'm sorry I'm a little new to all this and still learning. Is there a better alternative to creating user databases then using MySQL and php or are they the only option? Excuse my noobishness.

Comment: @Dagon That's the textbook definition of manual escaping. If that function call isn't made, tainted data is passed through.

Comment: Two tables is fine, and MySQL or any of the variants, like [MariaDB](http://mariadb.com), is a good place to start. It really depends on what kind of data you need to store.

Comment: we must read different textbooks\

Comment: @Dagon Automatic escaping is done by prepared statements. Everything else is manual. I'm not sure why this is controversial. If you must explicitly call the function, it's manual by definition since it involves programmer intervention.

Comment: TBH, I've never dealt with 2 different **databases** and sessions, but my guess is that sessions can't talk to each other on different databases, so it sounds like an out of scope issue here. I for one can't wrap my head around your code and logic here. Basically, what you need to do is  assign a session array to a post array and then pass that session to other pages (and query in a WHERE clause), then destroy the session on logout.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and never store passwords as plain-text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments:

> *"Basically, what you need to do is assign a session array to a post array and then pass that session to other pages (and query in a WHERE clause), then destroy the session on logout."*

So this is the logic you can use and as a basic example:

Sidenote:

It would most likely take me more time to go over your entire code to fix it. This was easier/faster.

```
<?php 

session_start();

$_POST['user'] = "John"; // Take the POST array from your named input

if (!isset($_SESSION['var'])) {

  $_SESSION['var'] = $_POST['user'];
} else {
  echo "It seems the session is already set " . $_SESSION['var'];
}
$username = $_SESSION['var'];

echo $username;
```

...then check if the session is set in subsequent pages and apply the same logic.

Also heed the comments left under your question.

Reference to destroy the session:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php