# PHP Private Session

Tags: php, mysql

i have a login page that once logged in redirects you to forum but i'm trying to make it so you can't access the forum without being logged in via the login page i made then redirects you to forum/directory
i have  php file called lock.php inside it is

```
<?php
include('../config.php');
session_start();
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

$ses_sql=mysql_query("select username from admin where username='$user_check' ");

$row=mysql_fetch_array($ses_sql);

$login_session=$row['username'];

if(!isset($login_session))
{
header("Location: ../login.php");
}
?>
```

So in the forum index.php i put

```
include('lock.php');
```

but for some reason it's still not working not really sure why

I have this small index that works but it doesn't work on the forum index

```
<?php

include('lock.php');

?>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta name="description" content="Secret"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="DarkKnight"/>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>test </title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>test <?php echo $login_session; ?></h1> 

<h2><a href="logout.php">Sign Out</a></h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check `if{...}` the session is set/not empty (and/or equal to something), `else{...}` and make sure the session is set and has been started inside all files using sessions. add an `exit;` after each header also.

Comment: hey, thanks for the comment i'm pretty new to this i just copied these files from a template where do i put the exit; after i include the lock.php?

Comment: after each `header...`.

Comment: still not working

Comment: `$_SESSION['login_user']` needs to be assigned somewhere. You're just doing `$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];` where the session array itself isn't equal/assigned to anything in your db. If you were to use `$_SESSION['login_user'] = "john";` (use an existing one of course) from your db, you will see that the session will be set and equal to a user.

Comment: However, and not knowing what the login form looks like, what you need to do is assign that (same) session array to the POST array of the username in question and then check to see if that session array is set in all pages using session.

Comment: Have a look at an answer I gave http://stackoverflow.com/a/38840851/1415724 and for this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/38840589/1415724 - all that's left for you to do is to pass that session array to the POST array from the form. You'll get it working, I'm sure. If you have any difficultites, let me know.

Comment: You should always call `exit;` immediately following a `header('location:..')` call, to be sure the current file stops running, it's a best practice thing.

Comment: so i should replace $user_check=$_SESSION['login_user']; with $_SESSION['login_user'] in the lock.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_SESSION['login_user']`

You should always call exit; immediately following a `header('location:..')` call, to be sure the current file stops running, it's a best practice thing. – ArtisticPhoenix S